# Defining a type that holds 3 int value

Tags: c++, variables

I'm new to C++ and could not figure out how can I define a variable that holds 3 values,
e.g. coordinates hold 2 values, as (x,y).

I tried:

```
typedef int U_K(int a,int b,int c);
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

I'd really appreciate a quick simple answer :)

Thanks!

edit:
So i did this :

```
struct U_K{
    float a,b,c;
};
    U_K Uk; //this line
```

is this wrong? because i get "unknown type name U_K" for that line... i first though its because i needed to declare it under the function i am going to use the struct for, but turns out there is the error for both cases.

Comment: Your (second) code works fine for me. What is your compiler? Are you sure, you compile it as C++ and `U_K Uk;` is under struct 
declaration?

Comment: -1 You appear to be using a C compiler and not a C++ compiler.

Comment: yes that's the mistake apperantly. but does that mean structs cannot be used in a .c source file or simply the syntax is diffrent?

Answer (score 5):

the shortest way is to use a `struct`

```
struct U_K
{
    int a,b,c;
};
```

usage:

```
U_K tmp;
tmp.a = 0;
tmp.b = 1;
tmp.c = 2;
```

You can add complexity to that type by adding member function/constructors to make the usage of `U_K` easier:

```
struct U_K
{
    int a,b,c;
    U_K() //default constructor
        :a(0)
        ,b(0)
        ,c(0)
    {}
    U_K(int _a_value,int _b_value, int _c_value) //constructor with custom values
        :a(_a_value)
        ,b(_b_value)
        ,c(_c_value)
    {}

};
//usage:
int main()
{
    U_K tmp(0,1,2);
    std::cout << "a = " << tmp.a << std::endl;//print a
    std::cout << "b = " << tmp.b << std::endl;//print b
    std::cout << "c = " << tmp.c << std::endl;//print c
}
```

Alternatively you can use [std::tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) to obtain the same result. Using it is different:

```
std::tuple<int,int,int> t = std::make_tuple(0,1,2);
std::cout << "a = " << std::get<0>(t) << std::endl;//print first member
std::cout << "b = " << std::get<1>(t) << std::endl;//print second member
std::cout << "c = " << std::get<2>(t) << std::endl;//print third member
```

**If you are learning c++ now** you should know that the implementation `std::tuple` is much more complex than a trivial struct and to understand it you need to learn about templates and variadic templates.

Comment: I'd even recommend going with a `std::tuple`, I don't think it's particularly difficult to use for a newbie.  `typedef std::tuple<int,int,int> U_K;`.

Comment: @GuyGreer: tuple would work well, but for a beginner, it is still important to know how to create their own structs.

Comment: @GuyGreer i added `std::tuple` also, but for learning purposes it would probably be best to use a normal struct.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct TypeWith3Ints
{
  public:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::array<int, 3>` which is to be preferred over tuple in this case as a homogenous container can be used.

If you want to typedef:

```
#include <array>
typedef std::array<int, 3> X;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [std::tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple), then you don't have to make your own structure. Just write

```
std::tuple<int, int, int> your_tuple(a,b,c);
std::cout << std::get<1>(your_tuple) << ' '; // b
your_tuple = std::make_tuple(c,d,e);
std::cout << std::get<0>(your_tuple) << ' '; // c
```

If you want your own name, use alias, like:

```
typedef std::tuple<int, int, int> your_name;
your_name your_object(a,b,c); //your_tuple
std::cout << std::get<2>(your_tuple) << ' '; // c
```

If you want, your own structure, and if you want to write `object(x,y,z)`, than you should make constructor or even overload operator `()`. It's more complicated. I suggest not to do it. Unless that has a deeper meaning. If you really want it, it could look like:

```
struct coordinate
 {
  int x,y,z;
  coordinate(int a, int b, int c) : x(a), y(b), z(c)
   {}
  void operator()(int a, int b, int c)
   {
    x = a;
    y = b;
    z = c;
   }
 } my_object(10,20,30);

int main()
 {
  std::cout<<my_object.x<<' '<<my_object.y<<' '<<my_object.z<<'\n';
  my_object(30,40,50);
  std::cout<<my_object.x<<' '<<my_object.y<<' '<<my_object.z<<'\n';
  return 0;
 }
```

You can also do not make constructor and use `{}` notation.